# Error with Format function

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with the Format() function in excel vba. I am trying to alter the formatting of a date formatted cell to change the way it is displayed. However, everytime i invoke Format to do that i get the error: "Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."

here is the code:

```
Sub test()
     Dim given
     given = DateSerial(2012, 10, 11)
     dateformat = Format(given, "dd/mm/yy")
     MsgBox given & vbCrLf & dateformat

 End Sub
```

This is just a test function and should function on its own and return "11/10/12". This code works on other computers. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Had this problem with code I put in a Worksheet_Activate() today and was pulling my hair out. Resolved it by changing Format to VBA.Format

So try:

```
 Sub test()
     Dim given
     given = DateSerial(2012, 10, 11)
     dateformat = VBA.Format(given, "dd/mm/yy")
     MsgBox given & vbCrLf & dateformat

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you might also have some **`Sub`** named **`Format`** somewhere else in your project.Hence you get the error.

Comment: I had this issue but do not have a sub/function with this name anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are declaring your `given` variable as a variant by default. Please declare it as `Date` data type. And to be safe, make sure you only send a `Date` using `CDate()` into the `Format()` to format as the date style you want.

Also DateSerial input should be in the following format. Which in your case alright. ;)

```
DateSerial(CInt(x), CInt(y), CInt(z)
```

Code snippet:

```
OPTION EXPLICIT '------------ please add this to your code to begin for better coding

Sub test()
     Dim given as Date '-------- define given as Date type
     Dim dateformat as Date
     given = DateSerial(2012, 10, 11)
     dateformat = Format(CDate(given), "dd/mm/yy") '--------- anyway wrap with CDate() to be sure
     MsgBox given & vbCrLf & dateformat

 End Sub
```

Comment: option explicit is always in there i just dont include it normally. I tried using cdate but got a different error message this time. It was expecting a variant not a module. Thank you for the attempt, i am giving up on the formatting issue for now. I wrote a work around that works fine, if a little inelegant.

Comment: I seriously forgot to ask you, as I assumed your `dateformat` variable is a `Date`....

Comment: you don't have a function / sub called "given", have you? In this case it would complain about wrong number of arguments as it expects given(...) as a function, and would complain when you use it in CDate. Just a thought (happened to me before). Just use a different variable name instead of 'given', see if this makes a difference. If it does, Vb has it defined somewhere else

Comment: @ssollinger look at his original code. Doesn't look like he is using a function called `given` which takes arguments.